# Browser is blocking my jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

So I'm not sure why but I get an error message from Chrome.

Error message:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-TakXxMuCq+J+ccgIY6WUXR+xy3/BdgRbqG7Y1mNRWJQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=440&count=3&maxlength=300&format=json'
      success: function(data){
        console.log('success',data);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Sorry if this is a duplicate question.
I just had a hard time finding the answer to my problem.
But can someone explain why I am getting the error message that I am getting?

I want to give some extra information, so that you may understand my situation.
I was writing an app in HTML.
All the files used in the HTML other then the JSON are all from my machine.
I did not run them from any server including `xampp`. I simply double clicked my HTML file.

Comment: if your page is served https, all your scripts need to be served https...?  You did include the <`script src="jQueryFile.min.js">` right?

Comment: Thanks for your response. All the files that i am using are not hosted on any servers but they are hosted on my local machine. I am not using anything like xampp btw.

Comment: put a `<script>` element directly before your closing `<body>` tag.  Inside it, paste the jquery code directly in there.

Comment: I did and it did not fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing a Chrome extension? It's not immediately clear from your question, but that's where I would expect to find this error message.

Inline `script` tags are not executed by extensions. The Google [Content Security Policy pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) state:

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both
>   inline `<script>` blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. `<button
>   onclick="...">`).
>
> The first restriction wipes out a huge class of cross-site scripting
>   attacks by making it impossible for you to accidentally execute script
>   provided by a malicious third-party. It does, however, require you to
>   write your code with a clean separation between content and behavior
>   (which you should of course do anyway, right?).

There is a way to relax this policy though

> As of Chrome 46, inline scripts can be whitelisted by specifying the
>   base64-encoded hash of the source code in the policy. This hash must
>   be prefixed by the used hash algorithm (sha256, sha384 or sha512). See
>   [Hash usage for `<script>` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-CSP2-20150721/#script-src-hash-usage) for an example.

Comment: Thankyou for your response i was not clear enough. I will update the question to be more clear. I was writing an app in html. I was trying to make an ajax call to a json file. I was running the code from my local machine. I wasnt using xampp or anything like that i simply ran the safed html on my machine.